# How to call parent function result in child function using angularjs and sqlite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

How to call parent function result in child function so that i can be able to alert() the result of parent function in child function

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status=1";  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(success) {
        for(var i=0;i<success.rows.length;i++){
            var queryw = "SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE inventory_id="+success.rows.item(i).id+"";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, queryw, []).then(function(sccess) {
            var kkk=0;
            if(sccess.rows.item(0).remain==''){kkk=0;}else{kkk=sccess.rows.item(0).remain;}
            alert(success.rows.item(i).id+'--'+success.rows.item(i).name+'--'+sccess.rows.item(0).remain);
            $scope.isuccs.push({id:success.rows.item(i).id,name:success.rows.item(i).name,price:success.rows.item(i).price,qty:kkk});
        },function (error) {alert("Error last inventory");
    });
    }
     $scope.selectedItem=[];
     $scope.selectedItem={price:''}; }, function (error) {
      //console.error(err);
      alert("Error retrieving inventory");
    });
```

Comment: Could you properly format the code in your question?

Comment: and in addition to that, explain what your question is.

Comment: how to call a defined result in a sub function like this 
.then(function(success){
       .then(function(succ){
/////output the result of the parent function here
});
});

Comment: if it is in laravel we could use function($query) use ($hj)

Comment: The main problem is that the alert is not working but it works when you remove success.rows.item(i).id+'--'+success.rows.item(i).name

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that a promise's success (or failure) callback will not trigger until after all the remaining code has finished executing. In particular your `for` loop will have finished executing so by the time you use it `i` always has the value `success.rows.length`. You have to extract the body of the loop out into a separate function to create a separate closure that will not be affected by the for loop.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status=1";
var queryw = "SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE inventory_id=?";
function get_inventory_item(row) {
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, queryw, [row.id]).then(function(sccess) {
        var kkk=0;
        if(sccess.rows.item(0).remain==''){
            kkk=0;
        }else{
            kkk=sccess.rows.item(0).remain;
        }
        alert(row.id+'--'+row.name+'--'+sccess.rows.item(0).remain);
        $scope.isuccs.push({
            id: row.id,
            name: row.name,
            price: row.price,
            qty:kkk
        });
    });
}   
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(success) {
    for(var i=0;i<success.rows.length;i++){
        get_inventory_item(success.rows.item(i);
    }
    $scope.selectedItem=[];
    $scope.selectedItem={price:''};
}, function (error) {
      //console.error(err);
    alert("Error retrieving inventory");
});
```

N.B. Also try to get into the habit of using parametrised sql queries rather than inserting parameters into the string itself.

I've resisted the temptation to restructure your code beyond laying it out legibly and doing the required extraction into a separate function, but I think you could probably end up with something much clearer if you made `get_inventory_item` return the promise and the success method in that function return the object it creates instead of pushing it into a scope object. The push is problematic because you don't know what order the values will be returned, if you returned the object then the main code body can use `$q.all()` to simply get an array of all the resulting values in the order returned by the original query.

Or, of course, an even simpler and faster solution would be to replace the pair of queries with a single query using `join` to get a complete row of all the fields together.

Comment: Thank you Duncan but what do you say about using promise with $q, do you think it will be wise? Because it is returning [object Object] when alert

Comment: Don't confuse a promise with the actual data: a promise is just an object with a `.then()` method to trigger success and failure callbacks. Any object will display `[object Object]` when passed to `alert()`, but `alert()` is a horrible way of tracing what is going on anyway. If you want to trace `something` use `$log.debug('a message', something)` and, at least in Chrome, you can then drill down through the attributes of `something` as far as you want.

Comment: just ran your script still not working. Callback will not trigger until after all the remaining code has finished executing. I want callback to trigger before the remaining code as it is arranged above

Comment: Code using promises will never trigger until the main body of code has returned. You must put any code you want to execute later inside a success callback.